# Within a span, limit the background-image size from a sprite

Tags: css

There is a list of items as a dropdown.

At the beginning of each line, there is reserved padding for the background image to display as the leading icon. The image is from a long vertical image sprite of icons. Now the problem is some line with long text would be wrapped into the next line, and since the height is increased, in the icon area, the underneath icon is displayed.

My question is, without changing the structure of the html, is there anyway to display one icon at each line no matter the height of the line is? Thanks a lot!

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="deactivate">
      <span>Deactivate the service</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="edit">
      <span>Edit </span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="delete">
      <span>Delete</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-hight: 1.25;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

a {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 3px;
}

a > span {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://cpqa.catchpoint.com/HawkUI/App_Themes/NewUI/images/icons/ico-db-sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.deactivate > span {
  background-position: -2px -382px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

a.delete > span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -2px -322px;
}

a.edit > span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -2px -362px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcdbLLfw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo element like this

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

a {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 3px;
}

a > span {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a > span:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://cpqa.catchpoint.com/HawkUI/App_Themes/NewUI/images/icons/ico-db-sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a.deactivate > span:before {
  background-position: -2px -382px;
}

a.delete > span:before {
  background-position: -2px -322px;
}

a.edit > span:before {
  background-position: -2px -362px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="deactivate">
      <span>Deactivate the service</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="edit">
      <span>Edit </span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="delete">
      <span>Delete</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

---

*Update based on comments*

If you want it to work in the existing background, you'll have to increase the space between each item in your `png` to make up for an extra line or 2, ... or you need a second image/background-color to cover the same.

Either way, a pseudo element will do this better, fully scalable, regardless the amount of lines an item has.

Well, you could also set a fixed height on your span (`height: 16px;`), like this

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-hight: 1.25;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

a {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 3px;
}

a > span {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://cpqa.catchpoint.com/HawkUI/App_Themes/NewUI/images/icons/ico-db-sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.deactivate > span {
  background-position: -2px -382px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

a.delete > span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -2px -322px;
}

a.edit > span {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -2px -362px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="deactivate">
      <span>Deactivate the service</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="edit">
      <span>Edit </span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="delete">
      <span>Delete</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think i am looking for something without extra padding.

Comment: @Z.Z. You mean the `padding-right: 8px`?, that you can easily adjust yourself, my answer show a way to achieve what you want with a sprite image ... I updated and took that one out and adjusted the pseudo width slightly to make it look more as in your post.

Comment: @Z.Z. If you want it to work in the existing background, you'll have to increase the space between each item in your `png` to make up for an extra line or 2, ... or you need a second image/background color to cover the same. .. Either way, a pseudo element will do this best, regardless the amount of lines an item have

Comment: yeah, i want to the icon in the existing background. Also, ideally, the icon can be sitting in the center vertically/

Comment: @Z.Z. Updated my answer ... came up with one more way how-to

Comment: I see, you added height to span. Thanks.